# R: creating column based on data from another dataframes

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe like this:

**Events**

| Date | City | Event |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2012-06-01 | LA | A |
| 2014-05-02 | London | B |
| 2017-03-15 | Paris | C |

And several dataframes like this:

**LA_weather**

| Date | Avtemp |
| --- | --- |
| 2012-06-01 | 23 |
| 2012-06-02 | 22 |
| ---------- | ----- |
| 2017-12-31 | 15 |

**London_weather**

| Date | Avtemp |
| --- | --- |
| 2012-06-01 | 16 |
| 2012-05-02 | 21 |
| ---------- | ----- |
| 2017-12-31 | 10 |

And similar for more than 10 cities. I want to add to Events column "Avtemp" based on date and condition (when City == LA we take data from LA_weather, when London from London_weather etc).

**Events (desired result)**

| Date | City | Event | Avtemp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2012-06-01 | LA | A | 23 |
| 2014-05-02 | London | B | 21 |
| 2017-03-15 | Paris | C | 10 |

Sorry, maybe it's a basic question, but I'm new in R and confused a little bit.

I can merge weather data for all cities to one large dataframe with creating column "City". And than merging this with Events but maybe there is more elegant way.

Comment: What you suggest (merge weather data for all cities then merge this with events) sounds good!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can merge weather data for all cities to one large dataframe with creating column "City". And then merging this with Events.

This is a good approach. Here’s a workflow:

```
library(dplyr)

# add example data for Paris
Paris_weather <- read.table(
  text = "Date  Avtemp
          2012-06-01    20
          2012-06-02    20
          2017-03-15    14", 
  header = TRUE
)

cities <- unique(Events$City)

Weather <- cities |>
  paste0("_weather") |>
  mget() |>
  setNames(cities) |>
  bind_rows(.id = "City")

left_join(Events, Weather)
```

```
        Date   City Event Avtemp
1 2012-06-01     LA     A     23
2 2014-05-02 London     B     NA
3 2017-03-15  Paris     C     14
```

(Note there’s no matching date for London in your example data.)